# Extending the exponential to complex

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

We have the exponential function is defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. However if we wanted to prove the existence of a continuous function $\exp:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ that is a function that extends $e^x$ to a complex domain and range, how would we go about it?

I know intuitively that:
for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, letting in general $z=a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ it holds that $e^z\in\mathbb{C}$. I also know that the exponential function is expanded with the general taylor series as $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ but this is strictly defined for the reals.

I am not sure how to go about this proof, it would seem that we would have to start with definining an entirely new function since the expansion only is defined on the reals.

Comment: Why do you think your power series is strictly defined for real $x$? The same series is convergent for all complex $x$ and works as nicely as any other approach (or perhaps in much simpler manner).

Answer (score 2):

Consider, for $z \in \mathbb C$, the power series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}.$$

It is easy to see that this power series has radius of convergence $= \infty$, hence it defines a function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$,

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}.$$

From the theory of power series it is known that $f$ is continuous on $ \mathbb C.$ Furthermore we have

$$f(x)=e^x$$

for all $x \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: How exactly can we assume the continuity of the series? In the last part where you equate $f(x)=e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ you are implying that the same function holds for the real, could we not just note that the imaginary part has a factor of zero, thus making it applicable to the reals?

Answer (score 0):

For showing continuity of a function , it is enough to show that $lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = f(z_0) $.
Since , $e^z$ is defined on all over $\mathbb{C} $ , so, for each $z_0$, $lim_{z\to z_0} e^z $ exists and equal to $e^{z_0}$

Edit : as you say , you begin with the assumption , exponential defined on whole $\mathbb{R} $.
Then, simply write $f(z)=e^z=e^x cos(y) + i (e^x sin(y)) = u(x,y)+i v(x,y) $.
Clearly, as, $e^x,cos(y),sin(y) $ defined on whole $\mathbb{R} $, from this we can conclude that
$u(x,y),v(x,y)$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}^2 $ , so, $f(z)$ defined on $\mathbb{C} $

Comment: But I wish not to begin with the assumption that $e^z$ is defined yet. I am only assuming that the exponential holds for $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to define a function that is the exponential but extended to the complex numbers. I dont want to assume that it is defined for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ to begin with.